# Copy Rows with PK feedback loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Given the following (Table1):

```
Id    Field1  Field2     ...
--    ------  -------
NULL  1        2
NULL  3        4
...
```

I'd like to insert the values of Field1 and Field2 into a different table (Table2).  Table2 has an auto increment integer primary key.  I want to retrieve the new PKs from Table2 and update the Id column above (Table1).

I realize this is not conventional - its not something I need to do regularly, simply one-off for some migration work.  I made some attempts using `INSERT INTO, OUTPUT, INSERTED.Id`, but failed.  The PKs that are "looped-back" into Table1 must tie to the values of Field1/Filed2 inserted.

Comment: Perhaps "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" after each insert into table2?

Comment: What code did you use for your INSERT INTO / OUTPUT / Inserted.Id attempt?  You should be able to get that to work.

Comment: Does Field1/Field2 make a unique key?

Comment: Tim - no, Field1/Field2 is not guaranteed to make a unique key.  So there has to be some kind of memory of the order of inserts.

Comment: mwigdahl - insert into Table2 (Field1, Field) OUTPUT Inserted.Id into Table1 Select Field1, Field2 From Table1.  Various attempts of that sort

Comment: @SFun28 if it's not guaranteed to make a unique key, you're kind of screwed. Databases have no logical concept of "order" of inserts. If you have a timestamp column, or a "inserted date" datetime column, you could use that.

Comment: Dmitriy - I think SCOPE_IDENTITY() only captures the last inserted row?

Comment: N West - ah!  that sucks.  Maybe I can just add another field to each table (like a GUID) and use that to join.

Comment: @SFun28 - You've indicated that there are additional columns in Table1, I assume there's a PK in there somewhere?

Comment: SFun28: Yeah. If this is a one time deal, I figured you could cursor over all records in tableA, read scope_identity after each insert into tableB and then update tableA back with the value.

Comment: Esoteric Screen Name - Unfortuantely there's no PK in Table1.  Just in Table2

Comment: @Dmitriy - yeah, perhaps one massive FOR loop is the way to go =)

Comment: @SFun28 See my updated answer. Just insert rows from t1 to t2, delete the rows from t1, and reinsert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to do a insert, then a delete and re-insert.

```
create table t1
( id int, f1 int, f2 int);

create table t2
( id int primary key IDENTITY , f1 int, f2 int);

insert into t1 (id, f1, f2) values (null, 1, 2);    
insert into t1 (id, f1, f2) values (null, 3, 4);
insert into t1 (id, f1, f2) values (null, 5, 6);
insert into t1 (id, f1, f2) values (null, 5, 6);

insert into t2 (f1, f2) 
select f1, f2 from t1 where id is null;

delete t1 
  from t1 join t2 on (t1.f1 = t2.f1 and t1.f2 = t2.f2);

insert into t1
select id, f1, f2 from t2;

select * from t1;
```

See this example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e630/1).

Comment: The issue is that my fields do not create a unique set of values.  Even if they did, I'd have to index all of them.  Imagine a large table with many fields.  Does that rule out your answer?

Comment: @SFun28 - You say the combination of 'Field1' and 'Field2' are not unique but, as far as a database is concerned, they are the same. I imagine you will have to delete the "duplicate" rows as you have no way of identifying them as different from any other matching row.

Comment: @SFun28 You don't have to index all of them - in this case a full scan is probably better since you are loading the records from one table to the other and filtering on all the columns. Multiple index scans will just be slow, one full scan will be fine. If your fields aren't unique, you could try inserting the records, then deleting from table 1 and reinserting. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need some type of unique key to match your rows in each table.  I've taken the liberty of adding a TempGuid column to each of your tables (which you can later drop):

```
-- Setup test data
declare @Table1 table (
      Id int null
    , Field1 int not null
    , Field2 int not null
    , TempGuid uniqueidentifier not null unique
)
insert into @Table1 (Field1, Field2, TempGuid) select 1, 2, newid()
insert into @Table1 (Field1, Field2, TempGuid) select 3, 4, newid()

declare @Table2 table (
      Id int not null primary key identity(1, 1)
    , Field1 int not null
    , Field2 int not null
    , TempGuid uniqueidentifier not null unique
)

-- Fill Table2
insert into @Table2 (Field1, Field2, TempGuid)
select Field1, Field2, TempGuid
from @Table1

-- Update Table1 with the identity values from Table2
update a
set a.Id = b.Id
from @Table1 a
    join @Table2 b on a.TempGuid = b.TempGuid

-- Show results
select * from @Table1
```

`Output` would be workable if you already had a unique key on Table1 that you were inserting into Table2.  You could also do a temporary unique key (perhaps GUID again) in a loop or cursor and process one row at a time, but that seems worse to me.

**UPDATE**

Here is the actual SQL to run on your tables:

```
-- Add TempGuid columns
alter table Table1 add TempGuid uniqueidentifier null
update Table1 set TempGuid = newid()
alter table Table2 add TempGuid uniqueidentifier not null

-- Fill Table2
insert into Table2 (Field1, Field2, TempGuid)
select Field1, Field2, TempGuid
from Table1

-- Update Table1 with the identity values from Table2
update a
set a.Id = b.Id
from Table1 a
    join Table2 b on a.TempGuid = b.TempGuid

-- Remove TempGuid columns
alter table Table1 drop column TempGuid
alter table Table2 drop column TempGuid
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have full control over the schema definitions, add a foreign key to `Table2` that references `Table1`'s primary key.
Perform your data insert:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Field1, Field2, T1PK)
SELECT Field1, Field2, PK FROM Table1
```

Then backfill Table1:

```
UPDATE t1 SET Id = t2.PK
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.T1PK = t1.PK
```

Then delete the extra column (`T1PK`) from `Table2`.

Edit:

Since there's no PK in `Table1`, just add one to `Table1`, use that, and then drop it at the end.

For example...

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN T1PK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT Table1_PK PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID();

ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD COLUMN T1PK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL

INSERT INTO Table2 (Field1, Field2, T1PK)
SELECT Field1, Field2, T1PK FROM Table1

UPDATE t1 SET Id = t2.PK
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.T1PK = t1.T1PK

ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP CONSTRAINT Table1_PK

ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN T1PK

ALTER TABLE Table2 DROP COLUMN T1PK
```

Comment: In his example, table 1 doesn't have a primary key - the ID field is blank and he needs to backfill it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty, but should do as a one time effort.

```
create table tableA
(
id int,
field1 int,
field2 int
)

create table tableB
(
id int identity(1,1),
field1 int,
field2 int
)

insert into tableA select NULL, 1, 2
insert into tableA select NULL, 2, 3

declare @field1_value int;
declare @field2_value int;
declare @lastInsertedId int;

DECLARE tableA_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    select field1, field2 from tableA

    OPEN tableA_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableA_cursor INTO @field1_value, @field2_value 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        insert into tableB select @field1_value, @field2_value
        set @lastInsertedId = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())
        update a
            set id = @lastInsertedId
            from tableA a
        where field1 = @field1_value
            and field2 = @field2_value
    print @field1_value

    FETCH NEXT FROM tableA_cursor 
    INTO @field1_value, @field2_value
    END
CLOSE tableA_cursor
DEALLOCATE tableA_cursor
```

With not exists check:

```
declare @field1_value int;
declare @field2_value int;
declare @lastInsertedId int;

DECLARE tableA_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    select field1, field2 from tableA

    OPEN tableA_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableA_cursor INTO @field1_value, @field2_value 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF NOT EXISTS    
            (
                select * from tableB 
                where field1 = @field1_value 
                and field2 = @field2_value   
            )    
            BEGIN
                insert into tableB 
                select @field1_value, @field2_value

                set @lastInsertedId = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

                update a
                    set id = @lastInsertedId
                    from tableA a
                where field1 = @field1_value
                    and field2 = @field2_value
            END     

    FETCH NEXT FROM tableA_cursor 
    INTO @field1_value, @field2_value
    END
CLOSE tableA_cursor
DEALLOCATE tableA_cursor
```

Comment: If you only need to insert unique combinations from tableA, then before insert, we just need to add "not exists" check; I'll add this variation to my answer.