# FETCH NEXT into table-like structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

All of the examples that I found of `FETCH NEXT` fetch `INTO` pre-defined variables.  So:

```
DECLARE @Whatever Int
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @Whatever
```

Is there a way to FETCH or otherwise deal with a cursor so that the entire row is accessible (like in a table) without having to define each variable?  So perhaps I can fetch into something other than a scalar?  Or can I query the cursor directly?

Comment: No, you can't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If this is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506294/copy-rows-with-pk-feedback-loop), you're much better off using a set based approach than a big loop.

Comment: That question triggered this one.  I'm mostly asking out of curiosity and to understand cursors better.

Comment: @podiluska - any reason you deleted your answer?  I was going to accept it.

Comment: @podiluska - the moderators are swift and heavy-handed =)

Comment: @SFun28 I'd put more effort into trying not to have to understand cursors. :) As a rule of thumb, they're inefficient and should be avoided if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can `UPDATE` or `DELETE` from a cursor using `WHERE CURRENT OF` but if you're selecting it needs to go into variables

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to repace the cursor with a table variable?  You'd be able to deal with the full row and would probably increase performance.

Post more of what you're trying to do and maybe we can help more...